# - vs _ with simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file, the parent and children use - instead of _ which I'm used to.

```
<the-parent>
   <the-children>Value</the-children>
</the-parent>
```

I have been using **simplexml_load_file()** to parse past xml files and putting it through a **foreach()** loop to echo everything back out.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->the-parent as $parent) {
   echo $parent->the-children;
}
```

I keep getting this error **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

I can't change the format of the xml file because I am getting it from a 3rd-party.  What are my options for parsing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like `$xml->{'the-parent'}`.

See example #3: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$x->{'the-parent'}` and `$parent->{'the-children'}` to access those values.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest reading the file into a string variable, replace the "-" chars and after that load the string with simplexml_load_string()

otherwise something like that should work:

```
$children = $xml->children();
foreach ($children as $element => $value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using string functions on raw xml? Not really a good idea. It'd be hard to do the replacements only for tags (no, <> around it is not enough - CDATA may contain &lt;something&gt; without <> being escaped)

Comment: @ZaneDeFazio: It cannot be used as a field name when using the `$object->field` syntax.